Error uploading node.js project on azure web app through Github CI/CD
I am uploading my node.js code on Azure web app. After a lot of try, I was able to successfully do it. I am building my code on Visual Studio and pushing to Github and using CI/CD connected to Azure web app. Recently, I connected my code to Azure MySQL server and after that, I have started getting error. I found in the logs that port 8080 is not working. Here's a snippet of the error:
[DATE] ERROR - Container [CONTAINER_ID] for site [SITE_NAME] has exited, failing site start

[DATE] ERROR - Container [CONTAINER_ID] didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.

[DATE] INFO  - Stopping site [SITE_NAME] because it failed during startup.

[DATE] Error details:

  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

  requireStack: [ '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js', '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/express/lib/application.js', '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/express/lib/express.js', '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/express/index.js', '/home/site/wwwroot/server.js'

  ]

[DATE] INFO  - Starting container for site

[DATE] INFO  - docker run -d --expose=8080 --name [CONTAINER_NAME] [ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES] appsvc/node:20-lts_[VERSION] node server.js

[DATE] INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container [CONTAINER_ID] for site [SITE_NAME]

[DATE] ERROR - Container [CONTAINER_ID] for site [SITE_NAME] has exited, failing site start

[DATE] ERROR - Container [CONTAINER_ID] didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.

[DATE] INFO  - Stopping site [SITE_NAME] because it failed during startup.

I am not using Docker. I am various measures to do it. Here's a screenshot of my Web app config. I have added port as 8080:

Here's my Github workflow:
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App

on:

  push:

    branches:

      - main

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:

  build-and-deploy:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:

    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Node.js version

      uses: actions/setup-node@v1

      with:

        node-version: '20.15.1'

    - name: Create .npmrc file

      run: echo "engine-strict=false" > .npmrc

    - name: Install server dependencies

      run: npm ci

    - name: Build client

      run: |

        cd client

        npm ci

        npm run build

        cd ..

    - name: Create deployment package

      run: |

        zip -r deploy.zip . -x "*.git*" "node_modules/*" "client/node_modules/*" "client/src/*" "client/public/*"

    - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'

      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2

      with:

        app-name: 'job-search'

        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}

        package: ./deploy.zip

    - name: Print server.js content

      run: |

        echo "Contents of server.js:"

        cat server.js

    - name: Print Node.js version

      run: node --version


Here's my server.js:
console.log('Starting server.js');

console.log('Environment variables:', {

  NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV,

  PORT: process.env.PORT,

  DB_HOST: process.env.DB_HOST,

  DB_USER: process.env.DB_USER,

  DB_NAME: process.env.DB_NAME

  // Don't log DB_PASSWORD

});

process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {

  console.error('Uncaught Exception:', err);

});

const express = require('express');

const cors = require('cors');

const cron = require('node-cron');

const path = require('path');

const { initializeDatabase } = require(path.join(__dirname, 'server', 'database'));

const { fetchAllJobs, searchJobs, getJobCategories, getCategoryCount, getTotalJobCount } = require(path.path.join(__dirname, 'server', 'jobLogic'));

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Middleware

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());

// Serve static files from the React app

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

app.get('/health', (req, res) => {

  res.status(200).send('OK');

});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {

  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'));

});

// Error handling middleware

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {

  console.error(err.stack);

  res.status(500).send('Something broke!');

});

app.use((req, res, next) => {

  res.status(404).send("404 - Not Found");

});

// Initialize database and start server

initializeDatabase()

  .then(() => {

    console.log('Database initialized successfully');

    return new Promise((resolve) => {

      const server = app.listen(port, () => {

        console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}`);

        resolve(server);

      });

    });

  })

  .then((server) => {

    console.log('Server started successfully');

    return fetchAllJobs();

  })

  .then(() => {

    console.log('Initial job fetch completed');

  })

  .catch(error => {

    console.error('Error during startup:', error);

    process.exit(1);

  });

// Schedule job fetching (every 6 hours)

//cron.schedule('0 */6 * * *', fetchAllJobs);

This is package.json for server level:
{
  "name": "job-search",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.12",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "csv-parser": "^3.0.0",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "lottie-react": "^2.4.0",
    "mysql2": "^3.10.3",
    "node-cache": "^5.1.2",
    "node-cron": "^3.0.3",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "sqlite": "^5.1.1",
    "sqlite3": "^5.1.7",
    "us-state-codes": "^1.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "cd client && npm install && npm run build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "postinstall": "npm run build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "20.15.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.8",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "nodemon-webpack-plugin": "^4.8.2",
    "start-server-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.5",
    "webpack": "^5.93.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  }
}


I am trying various steps to solve it. But it seems my main issue is with port 8080. Any help with be appreciated.

If possible, Share your Github repo?

Are you Deploying both client and server app to the same Azure App Service?

Hi, yes I am deploying both to the same app service. I have the client side in a folder called "Client". The server is located at the root. this is my structure of the project. Is it possible to share any code file? (My git currently contains some sensitive items, I can definitely remove and share the entire git if needed). Thank you!

From the error message it states that the main issue is originating from /home/site/wwwroot/server.js and that looks to be at the root of you project.

There could be high possibility that package.json is missing in this
root level.

So, either you create a new package.json in the root of your project that has all the packages required in the server.js or move you existing package.json to root level.
   /node_modules
   /client
   /server.js
   /package.json

And since the GitHub Actions Workflow is already doing a npm ci at root level hopefully this should server the server.js on port 8080.

The error you are facing is not about Http pings, It is related to Module_Not_Found. Which means the files are not deployed to Azure correctly.

code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: [
'/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js',
'/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/express/lib/application.js',
'/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/express/lib/express.js',
'/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/express/index.js',
'/home/site/wwwroot/server.js'
]

Check Kudu to see if the files are deployed correctly.

Open below URL to see the files.
https://<YourAzurewebappName>.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui

Open FileManager => Site => wwwroot, here you can find your deployed files.



Project Structure:

Below is my code.
server.js:
require('dotenv').config();
console.log('Starting server.js');
console.log('Environment variables:', {
  NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV ,
  PORT: process.env.PORT,
  DB_HOST: process.env.DB_HOST,
  DB_USER: process.env.DB_USER,
  DB_PASSWORD:process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  DB_NAME: process.env.DB_NAME
});
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  console.error('Uncaught Exception:', err);
});
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const { initializeDatabase } = require('./server/database');
const { fetchAllJobs } = require('./server/jobLogic');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.get('/api/jobs', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const jobs = await fetchAllJobs();
    res.json(jobs);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching jobs:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error fetching jobs' });
  }
});
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
app.get('/health', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send('OK');
});
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'));
});
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.status(404).send("404 - Not Found");
});
initializeDatabase()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Database initialized successfully');
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const server = app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}`);
        resolve(server);
      });
    });
  })
  .then((server) => {
    console.log('Server started successfully');
    return fetchAllJobs();
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Initial job fetch completed');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error during startup:', error);
    process.exit(1);
  });

server/jobLogic.js:
const { getConnection } = require('./database');
async function fetchAllJobs() {
  const connection = getConnection();
  const [rows] = await connection.execute('SELECT * FROM jobs');
  return rows;
}
module.exports = {
  fetchAllJobs
};

Client/JobList.js:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
function JobList() {
  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchJobs() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('https://kanodejamysqlapp.azurewebsites.net/api/jobs'); 
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        setJobs(data);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }
    fetchJobs();
  }, []);
  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error fetching jobs: {error.message}</p>;
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {jobs.map((job) => (
          <li key={job.id}>{job.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
export default JobList;

GitHub Workflow:
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - kanodejamysqlapp
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18.x'
      - name: Install backend dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Install frontend dependencies and build client
        run: |
          cd client
          npm install
          chmod +x node_modules/.bin/react-scripts
          npm run build
      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip -r release.zip ./*
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: node-app
      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip
      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
        with:
          app-name: 'kanodejamysqlapp'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_<secret_key> }}

Azure App Service Output:


@Gaurav Kispotta Please check if the solution above helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.
